# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

Tags: flutter

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)
E/flutter (16028): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
E/flutter (16028): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (16028): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
E/flutter (16028): #2      MethodChannelImagePicker.pickImagePath (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:62:21)
E/flutter (16028): #3      MethodChannelImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:30:25)
E/flutter (16028): #4      ImagePicker.getImage (package:image_picker/image_picker.dart:101:21)
```

Comment: It might be better to at least put some text and a real question, instead of just dropping a stacktrace. That would make reading your "question" far more enjoyable.

Answer (score 5):

**STEP 1 :** Ensure you have imported the plugin by including this in your **pubspec.yaml** file

`image_picker: ^0.6.7+4`

**STEP 2 :** Make sure you have **imported** the plugin in the file you need it

`import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';`

**STEP 3 :** Make sure you run this command

`flutter pub get`

Now, many times in Flutter even after doing the above 3 steps **perfectly** you will get the same error.

Here is my solution that has worked for me.

**STEP 1 :** Run this command in the terminal
`flutter clean`

**STEP 2 :** **CLOSE/STOP** your emulator and start it **again**

99% of the time this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

just click stop red icon right side of run icon. and restart app